# Maintaining quantities of products in database

Tags: mysql, table, architecture

I am building one online bakery store. Here I will have to manage products like cakes and pastries. A half kg cake could have price of 250 where as 1 kg cake will have price of 450. That is, it doesn't double the price. So how should I  manage this situation which holds for various products across the tables. Should I keep any separate table to maintain slabs (for 1 kg 50% increment)? Any suggestions are most welcomed, as currently I am working over the architecture of the database for this store.

Answer (score 2):

If there are arbitrary prices for each pastry and weight thereof, then they would need to be stored individually. That is unless there is a common multiplier that can be applied to the weight of the pastry to get its price.

If a pastry will always be the same price and only sold in specific weight values - then this is a one-to-many relationship (one pastry can have many prices - determined by different weights) then you would want a pastry table, and a pricing table.The pricing table would contain the price, the weight, and a foreign key to the pastry table.

However, if there is a common multiplier that can be applied to the weight to determine price - then you would only need one table - for pastries. The multiplier is functionally dependent on the pastry, and therefore would be stored in the pastry table. This assumes you aren't going to keep track of historical multipliers - or that the multiplier won't change.

Without more detail I had to make some assumptions in my answer. You should derive the functional dependencies for your schema, then follow the normalization rules.